# Using preg_match to Find URL

Tags: php, string, url, expression, preg-match

I've been trying to use preg_match to find a form with a certain action URL.
Here the code

```
if (!preg_match('/<form method="post" 
action="https[\:]//www.amazon.com/gp/aw/si.html/ref=aw_c_co".*?<\/form>/is', $page, $form)) {
die('Failed to CHECKOUT form!');
```

But I get an error message:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/'
```

I dont understand whats wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape (\) the / since these are your regex delimiters! Maybe you want to use other delimiters?

/ -> \/

Comment: To avoid "toothpick syndrome" (all those \ and /), change your outer pattern delimiters from / to something else like ~ or #. You don't need to escape a colon : but you should escape literal periods: `'~<form method="post" action="https://www\.amazon\.com/gp/aw/si\.html/ref=aw_c_co".*?</form>~is'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
$str = '<form method="post" action="https[\:]//www.amazon.com/gp/aw/si.html/ref=aw_c_co".*?<\/form>';
$str = preg_replace('^.*<form.*?action="(.+?)".*$', '$1', $str);
```

It give you : https[\:]//www.amazon.com/gp/aw/si.html/ref=aw_c_co

Good luck